# Suppress reminder dialog

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm using a recurring task to trigger a macro in Outlook, using the Application_Reminder hook.

However when the task fires, I want to suppress the Reminder dialog box which normally appears (where there are Dismiss/Snooze etc buttons).

I've tried

```
Item.ReminderTime = DateAdd("h", 1, Now)
```

which does work, but causes the task time to move forward, whereas I want it to remain at a fixed time.

Answer (score 1):

Reminders object (returned by Aplication.Reminders property) exposes the BeforeReminderShow event, which passes Cancel parameter by reference. Set it to true. When a reminder fires, the following events fire:

```
ReminderChange (IDispatch)
ReminderFire (IDispatch)
BeforeReminderShow (false)
```

Answer (score -1):

See the posts in the [Add-In Express forum](http://www.add-in-express.com/forum/read.php?FID=5&TID=646) in which the BeforeReminderShow event is proposed as a solution. It seems the event is a custom event, part of an add-in.